# Automatically refreshing Debian Wheezy KDE Plasma Desktop

Tags: plasma

I have a script which deletes files from my desktop. But after the files are deleted they continue to show as desktop icons. I have to refresh the desktop manually (F5) to get them to go away. I'd like to refresh the desktop from my BASH script. Anyone know how I can do that for a KDE Plasma Desktop on Debian Wheezy?

Answer (score 0):

In the end this worked:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/desktop" -a -f "$HOME/desktop/finish.desktop" ]; then
  touch "$HOME/desktop/finish.tmp"
  rm "$HOME/desktop/finish.tmp"
fi
```

I.e. creating a temp file in the desktop and then deleting it...